# Proving in a Hilbert system that $\neg A\Rightarrow A$ is a theorem, if assuming $\neg A$ makes it contradictory

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus, hilbert-calculus

Consider a Hilbert system $\mathcal{T}$ with modus ponens as the unique deduction rule, and subject to the following four axioms:

> For any relations $R,S$ and $T$ of $\mathcal{T}$, the relations
>
> 1. $(R\lor R)\Rightarrow R$,
> 2. $R\Rightarrow (R\lor S)$,
> 3. $(R\lor S)\Rightarrow (S\lor R)$, and
> 4. $(R\Rightarrow S)\Longrightarrow ((R\lor T)\Rightarrow (S\lor T))$,
>
> are also theorems (true relations) of $\mathcal{T}$.

Now let $A$ be a relation of $\mathcal{T}$, and consider a Hilbert system $\mathcal{T}'$, with modus ponens as well and subject to the same four axioms plus this fifth one:

> - $\neg A$

**Question:** How could one directly prove by pure and straight forward propositional calculus means that if $\mathcal{T}'$ is contradictory, then $\neg A\Rightarrow A$ must be a theorem of $\mathcal{T}$, and this *without* invoking nor paraphrasing the deduction lemma nor any other sophisticated compactness result?

At most, one can use the following 5 results:

> LT 1 : If $R\Rightarrow S$ and $S\Rightarrow T$, then $R\Rightarrow T$.
>
> LT 2 : $R\Rightarrow R$.
>
> LT 3 : $R\Leftrightarrow\neg(\neg R)$.
>
> LT 4 : $(R\Rightarrow S)\Longleftrightarrow(\neg S\Rightarrow\neg R)$.
>
> LT 5 : $R\land S\Rightarrow R$ and $R\land S\Rightarrow S$ are both true.

***Raison d'être...*** Since the hypothesis of this problem has already startled more than one, I'm gonna delve further into what I'm out to get.

Whether I'm using "an incomplete relevant sort of logic" or just fooling myself around, that I don't know, but in any case the Hilbert system I've just described is the starting setting of Bourbaki's *Théorie des ensembles*, as well as that of Godement's *Cours d'algèbre*. Precisely after having only proved LT1,$\ldots$, LT5, and nothing else, the latter author discusses *reductio ad absurdum*, and states that

> *This method of proof that $R$ is true consists in temporarily adjoining $\neg R$ to the axioms of mathematics and showing that the "new" mathematics so obtained is contradictory; by* Remark 5 [cf. op. cit., p. 29], *every relation is true in the new system, and in particular $R$ itself. Hence $R$ is a logical consequence of the (usual) axioms of mathematics and the relation $\neg R$; and this means, **as is easily seen**, that the relation* $$\neg R\Rightarrow R$$ is true *(in ordinary mathematics, i.e., in the original system to which we have now returned).*

Needless to say that by "(usual) axioms of mathematics" Godement means those that I have posted above, and that that devilish "as is easily seen" has driven me nuts!!!

It just remains to prove that now one can actually reach $R$. From $\neg R\Rightarrow R$ and (4), Godement deduces that $$(\neg R\Rightarrow R)\Longrightarrow [(\neg R \lor R)\Rightarrow(R \lor R)]$$ is true, and since it has been already been found that $\neg R\Rightarrow R$ is a theorem, the relation$$(\neg R \lor R)\Rightarrow(R \lor R)$$ is true as well. Certainly you would not object the truthfulness of $\neg R \lor R$, so by (3) and modus ponens $R\lor R$ is true, and from (1) it finally follows that $R$ is true.

Bourbaki essentially does the same, but immediately after having proved at length the deduction lemma, which he formulates as follows:

> *Let $A$ be a relation of $\ \mathcal{T}$, and $\ \mathcal{T}'$ the theory obtained by adjoining $A$ to the axioms of $\ \mathcal{T}$. If $B$ is a theorem of $\ \mathcal{T}'$, then $A\Rightarrow B$ is a theorem of $\ \mathcal{T}$*.

Comment: What is "your" definition of *contradictory* formula ? If a formula $R$ is called *contradictory* when it is always *false*, then $\lnot R \rightarrow R$ cannot be a theorem; due to the *soundness* of the calculus, all theorems must be *tautology*, i.e. always *true*. But $\lnot R \rightarrow R$ is $True \rightarrow False$, when $R$ is *false*, so that (truth-table for $rightarrow$) it is $False$.

Comment: A _contradictory_ formula is one that is _both_ true and false at once in a given system, not just false.

Comment: Why in the context of classical logic does it sound strange to you to talk about such a formula, if when you're trying to prove $A$ by _reductio ad absurdum_ what you actually do is to pass form $\mathcal{T}$ to $\mathcal{T}'$, and then somehow realize that the latter is contradictory, namely, that $A$ _is_ contradictory in $\mathcal{T}'$, in order to go back to $\mathcal{T}$ knowing already that $A$ must be true.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA  Mauro tricked me in answering this question as well (no hard feelings, yet) To he original Questioner:

You don't seem to have the standard weakening and self-distribution axioms for $ \Rightarrow $ also you don't seem to have any axioms for $ \Leftrightarrow $ and also no \land $ introduction axiom. Can the missing axioms be used or do you really mean to use some strange incomplete relevant logic?

Comment: @Willemien - it is worth noting that the four *axioms* of the question are exactly : *(Taut), (Add), (Perm)* and *(Sum)*, i.e. the four propositional axioms of W&R, *Principia Mathematica* (1910) [the fifth one : *(Assoc)* has been proved to be derivable by the others by Paul Bernays, “Axiomatische Untersuchungen des Aussagen-Kalkuls der “Principia Mathematica”, (1926)]. So, it "makes sense" (at least historically) trying to prove the result without *Deduction Theorem*, that was unknown to Russell (was formulated by Tarski and Herbrand independently in 1930).

Comment: About Godement - it mix truth and provability, and this is **not** sound. Saying, in general, that $\lnot R \rightarrow R$ is true ("in ordinarymathematics") makes little sense. In the case that $R$ is *false*, the conditional $\lnot R \rightarrow R$ is simply *false* (check with truth-tables). The "argument" must be read in semantical context : saying that $\Gamma \cup \{ \lnot R \}$ is *inconsistent* means that it is *unsatisfiable* (i.e.there are **no** models in which all of $\Gamma$ plus $\lnot R$ are *true*. **If** we assume that $\Gamma$ is *consistent*, then it is *satisfiable*;... 1/2

Comment: ... this implies that in every model of $\Gamma$ $\lnot R$ must be *false*. Due to the the law of excluded middle we are assuming in our (classical) semantics, if $\lnot R$ is *false*, then $R$ is *true*. So the "argument" boils down to : in every model of $\Gamma$, $R$ is true. This is the standard definition of *logical consequence* and, in virtue of the completeness of the proof system, this amount to : $R$ is *provable*. 2/2

Comment: No, I'm not looking for another proof of the deduction lemma, but for an explicit calculus of, one more time, $\neg A\Rightarrow A$ in $\mathcal{T}$ knowing already that $\mathcal{T}'$ is inconsistent (now I'm employing your term provided that mine troubles you so much). What makes me think that this is possible is the sheer fact that we are not using a $B$ whatsoever, but exactly $A$, what in principle should simplify everything.

Comment: Regarding Godement, he defines a _true relation_, or a _theorem_, as a formula that can be obtained by repeated application of the four above-mentioned axioms and modus ponens. So, when he affirms that $\neg R\Rightarrow R$ is true in the "ordinary mathematics", he's referring to a _concrete and specific_ assembly of symbols $R$, not to every possible formula; $R$ is not a "variable".

Comment: Thank you for your historical "ten cents", but the result makes sens _per se_ as a sheer exercise in propositional calculus, no more, no less, and not just as a historical "rarity".

Comment: Is "$\lor$" a primitive or a defined symbol of the system?

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA It's not clear to me that those axioms are the axioms of *any edition* of Principia Mathematica.  What are the definitions in the Bourbaki system?  If I recall correctly, in Principia Mathematica the axioms in their definition-free form actually changed from one of the earlier editions.  "A" and "N" were primitives in the earlier edition, and then the Sheffer Stroke "D" became a primitive in a later edition.  Does Bourbaki define the other connectives in terms of "D"?

Comment: @DougSpoonwood - 1st ed - see [Principia Mathematica](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principia_Mathematica) : **Primitive propositions**.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA So, then the axioms are *in full* (and in Lukasiewicz notation) 1. ANArrr, 2. ANrArs 3. ANArsAsr, 4. ANANrsANrtAst (this is useful in an automated context).  Substituting "r" in axiom 2 with the new axiom Na we have ANNaANas.  So, we detach (more like "resolve" when I think about it), ANas.  Then substituting a with Na in ANas yielding ANNas, we can resolve to s.  Then we can substitute s with ANNaa.

Answer (score 1):

See Nicolas Bourbaki, [Théorie des ensembles](http://books.google.it/books?id=VDGifaOQogcC&printsec=frontcover&dq=bourbaki+theorie+des+ensembles&hl=it&sa=X&ei=8ZmEVJjnPMOtUdLdgGA&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=bourbaki%20theorie%20des%20ensembles&f=false) (2nd ed, 1970), page I.22 :

> Une relation est dite fausse dans $\mathcal T$ si sa négation est un théorème de $\mathcal T$. On dit qu'une théorie $\mathcal T$ est contradictoire [*inconsistent*] quand on a écrit une relation qui est à la fois vraie et fausse dans $\mathcal T$ [i.e. both $\mathcal T \vdash \phi$ and $\mathcal T \vdash \lnot \phi$].

See Dirk van Dalen, [Logic and Structure](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1447145577) (5th ed, 2013), page 40 :

> $\mathcal{T}$ is *consistent* iff for no $\phi$, $\mathcal{T} \vdash \phi$ and $\mathcal{T} \vdash \lnot \phi$.

We have the following *Lemma* [see van Dalen, page 41] :

> if $\mathcal{T} \cup \{ \lnot A \}$ is *inconsistent*, then $\mathcal{T} \vdash A$.

It is easy to prove it with the *Deduction Theorem* : if $\mathcal{T} \cup \{ \lnot A \}$ is *inconsistent*, then we have : $\mathcal{T} \cup \{ \lnot A \} \vdash \lnot C$ and $\mathcal{T} \cup \{ \lnot A \} \vdash C$.

Applying the *DT* we have :

> $\mathcal{T} \vdash \lnot A \rightarrow \lnot C$

and

> $\mathcal{T} \vdash \lnot A \rightarrow C$.

But $\vdash (\lnot A \rightarrow \lnot C) \rightarrow ((\lnot A \rightarrow C) \rightarrow A)$ (it is a *tautology*), so that, by *modus ponens* twice :

> $\mathcal{T} \vdash A$.

Finally, we have that :

> $\vdash A \rightarrow (\lnot A \rightarrow A)$, (it is a *tautology*).

So, it is sufficient to apply *modus ponens* in order to have :

> $\mathcal{T} \vdash \lnot A \rightarrow A$.

In order to complete the proof, we need to derive the above tautologies from the axioms.

As you can see in Bourbaki, page I.27, the

> *Méthode de l'hypothèse auxiliaire* - Elle repose sur la règle suivante: (critère de la déduction). Soient $A$ une relation [formula] de $\mathcal T$, et $\mathcal T'$ la théorie obtenue en adjoignant $A$ aux axiomes de $T$. Si $B$ est un théorème de $\mathcal T'$, $A \rightarrow B$ est un théorème de $\mathcal T$.

is exactly the *Deduction Theorem* and it is proved exactly as in a standard mathematical logic textbook like Mendelson.

The following theorem : *Méthode de réduction à l'absurde* is exactly van Dalen's Lemma [page 41] I've used above.

Bourbaki's proof is based on "[le] méthode de l'hypothèse auxiliaire", exactly as made above.

The proof amount to: being $\mathcal T'$ *inconsistent*, it can prove everything, included $A$; so that :

*(a)* from $\mathcal T \cup \{ \lnot A \} \vdash A$, by *Deduction Theorem* :

*(b)* $\mathcal T \vdash \lnot A \rightarrow A$

*(c)* $\mathcal T \vdash (A \lor \lnot A) \rightarrow (A \lor A)$ --- using axiom 4 and *modus ponens*

*(d)* $\mathcal T \vdash (A \lor A)$ --- using the *tautology* $A \lor \lnot A$ and *modus ponens*

*(e)* $\mathcal T \vdash A$ --- using axiom 1 and *modus ponens*.

Comment: The fact that $\mathcal{T}\vdash A$ if $\mathcal{T}'$ is contradictory, that's the last part of the matter, the same that can be deduced from the four axioms I gave and from knowing already that $\neg A\Rightarrow A$ _is_ a theorem of $\mathcal{T}$, what precisely I'm aiming to prove.

Comment: The relation $A\Rightarrow (\neg A\Rightarrow A)$ is indeed a tautology in both $\mathcal{T}$ and $\mathcal{T}'$, and so since $\mathcal{T}'\vdash A$, by modus ponens $\mathcal{T}'\vdash (\neg A\Rightarrow A)$, what is clear enough (anyway, $\mathcal{T}'$ is contradictory), but why should it be $\mathcal{T}\vdash (\neg A\Rightarrow A)$ as well? That is exactly my question.

Comment: For one thing, after your last edit to this answer of yours, it is clear that you haven't understood my question yet, since what you have written down is precisely the opposite of what I'm asking for, that is to say, to do all that without the deduction lemma.

Comment: For a second thing, van Dalen states _reductio ad absurdum_ as one of his deduction rules, which I don't take for granted, but instead I'm going later to derive it from my impasse once I'm done with it, so your reference doesn't help me either.

Comment: I'm afraid that before editing this answer of yours for the last time, this early morning you didn't read carefully my last editing of my question, because otherwise you would've realized that I had already quoted Bourbaki's formulation of the deduction lemma and from it derived the proof of _reductio ad absurdum_ just as you did.

Answer (score 0):

I use Lukasiewicz/Polish notation.  This answer will suppose that we have disjunction "A" is an abbreviation for "CN".  Or that Apq is defined as CNpq.  Thus, the axioms become:

1. C CNrr r.
2. C r CNrs.
3. C CNrs CNsr.
4. C Crs C CNrt CNst.

We have a new axiom:

5. Na.

Now in axiom 2 let's substitute axiom 2 for "r".  This yields:

6. C CrCNrs CNCrCNrs s.

Detachment of 6 and 3 yields:

7. CNCrCNrs s.

Now substituting "a" with CrCNrs in 5. we obtain:

8. NCrCNrs.

Detachment of 7 and 8 yields:

9. s.

Substituting "s" with CrNr we have CrNr.

Since CrNr is a theorem of this new calculus (ahem... one-valued logic), and CpCqp is a law in this calculus your result follows, by detaching C CrNr C q CrNr and CrNr, where "q" is the antecedent of your "if-then" statement.

Answer (score 0):

We can prove it in the following way, with some additionsl *Lemmas*, reffering to :

- Roger Godement, [Algebra](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B0006E00F0) [1968 - English translation of *Cours d'Algèbre* (1963)].

The four logical axioms are those listed above [see page 26-27] and the relation of *logical implication* : $R \Rightarrow S$ [read : $R$ implies $S$, see page 27] is an abbreviation for :

> $S$ or (not $R$) [i.e. : $\lnot R \lor S$].

---

*Lemma 1* : if $\vdash A \Rightarrow B$ and $\vdash B \Rightarrow C$, then $\vdash A \Rightarrow C$ [see (TL1), page 27].

1) $A \Rightarrow B$ --- premise

2) $B \Rightarrow C$ --- premise

3) $(B \Rightarrow C) \Rightarrow ((B \lor \lnot A) \Rightarrow (C \lor \lnot A))$ --- from Ax.4 with $B$ in place of $R$, $C$ in place of $S$ and $\lnot A$ in place of $T$

4) $(B \Rightarrow C) \Rightarrow ((A \Rightarrow B) \Rightarrow (A \Rightarrow C))$ --- from 3) by abbreviation for $\Rightarrow$

5) $(A \Rightarrow B) \Rightarrow (A \Rightarrow C)$ --- from 4) and 2) by *Modus Ponens* [see (TR2), page 25]

> 6) $A \Rightarrow C$ --- from 5) and 2) by *MP*.

---

*Lemma 2* : $\vdash A \lor \lnot A$

1) $((A \lor A ) \Rightarrow A) \Rightarrow [((A \lor A) \lor \lnot A) \Rightarrow (A \lor \lnot A)]$ --- from Ax.4 with $A \lor A$ in place of $R$, $A$ in place of $S$ and $\lnot A$ in place of $T$

2) $((A \lor A) \lor \lnot A) \Rightarrow (A \lor \lnot A)$ --- from 1) and Ax.1 by *MP*

> 3) $A \lor \lnot A$ --- from Ax.2 and 2) by *MP* [by abbreviation,  $(A \lor A) \lor \lnot A$ can be rewritten as : $A \Rightarrow (A \lor A)$].

---

*Lemma 3* : if $\vdash A \Rightarrow C$ and $\vdash B \Rightarrow C$, then $\vdash (A \lor B) \Rightarrow C$ [see (TL6), page 29].

1) $A \Rightarrow C$ --- premise

2) $A \lor B \Rightarrow C \lor B$ --- from 1) and Ax.4 by *MP*

3) $A \lor B \Rightarrow B \lor C$ --- from 2) and Ax.3 by *Lemma 1*

4) $B \Rightarrow C$ --- premise

5) $B \lor C \Rightarrow C \lor C$ --- from 4) and Ax.4 by *MP*

6) $A \lor B \Rightarrow C \lor C$ --- from 3) and 5) by *Lemma 1*

> 7) $A \lor B \Rightarrow C$ --- from 6) and Ax.1 by *Lemma 1*.

---

*Lemma 4* :  if $\vdash A \Rightarrow C$ and $\vdash \lnot A \Rightarrow C$, then $\vdash C$ [see *Remark* on **reductio ad absurdum**, page 29].

1) if $\vdash A \Rightarrow C$ and $\vdash \lnot A \Rightarrow C$, then $\vdash (A \lor \lnot A) \Rightarrow C$ --- from *Lemma 3*, with $\lnot A$ in place of $B$

> 2) if $\vdash A \Rightarrow C$ and $\vdash \lnot A \Rightarrow C$, then $\vdash C$ --- from 1) and *Lemma 1*, by *MP*.

---

*Lemma* 5 : if $\vdash A \Rightarrow B$, then $\vdash A \Rightarrow (C \lor B)$ and $\vdash A \Rightarrow (B \lor C)$.

1) $A \Rightarrow B$ --- premise

> 2) $A \Rightarrow (B \lor C)$ --- from 1) and Ax.2 by *Lemma 1*
>
> 3) $A \Rightarrow (C \lor B)$ --- from 2) and Ax.3 by *Lemma 1*.

---

According to Godement's book, a relation is *contradictory* if it is both true and false [page 25]; thus [page 28] if we have a contradictory relation in the system, we can prove every relation, due to :

*Lemma 6* : $\vdash A \Rightarrow (\lnot A \Rightarrow B)$.

1) if $\vdash A \Rightarrow \lnot \lnot A$, then $\vdash A \Rightarrow (\lnot \lnot A \lor C)$ --- from *Lemma 5* with $\lnot \lnot A$ in place of $B$

2) $\vdash A \Rightarrow (\lnot A \Rightarrow C)$ --- from 1) and (TL3) [page 28 : $R \Leftrightarrow \lnot \lnot R$] by *MP*, with the abbreviation for $\Rightarrow$

---

---

Now for the proof of :

> if $\mathcal T \cup \{ \lnot A \}$ is contradictory, then $\lnot A \Rightarrow A$ must be a theorem of $\mathcal T$.

We have two possibility :

*(i)* according to Nicolas Bourbaki, [Théorie des ensembles](http://books.google.it/books?id=VDGifaOQogcC&printsec=frontcover&dq=bourbaki+theorie+des+ensembles&hl=it&sa=X&ei=8ZmEVJjnPMOtUdLdgGA&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=bourbaki%20theorie%20des%20ensembles&f=false) (2nd ed, 1970), page I.27, we can use *la méthode de l'hypothèse auxiliaire* (the *deduction theorem*).

This proof technique is quoted by Godement in *Remark 7* [page 34] as the *method of auxiliary hypothesis*.

*(ii)* We can use a "semantic" argument, using the concept of *logical consequence*, as done by Godement [see page 25] :

> "$R$ implies $S$" is [a] *true* [relation; see page 25 : or a *theorem*, i.e. $\vdash R \Rightarrow S$] means that $S$ is a *logical consequence* of $R$.

Thus we can use the usual properties of *logical consequence*, left implicit by Godement : we have that if $A$ is a *theorem* of a theory $\mathcal T$ [where we identify the *theory* with its set of *axioms*] then $A$ is a *logical consequence* of the axioms of $\mathcal T$ [i.e. whenever the axioms are true, also $A$ is].

Thus, if $\mathcal T \cup \{ \lnot A \}$ is contradictory, every relation is a theorem of the system [see *Remark 5*, page 28]. In particular, also $A$ is, i.e. $A$ is a *logical consequence* of $\mathcal T \cup \{ \lnot A \}$.

Writing $T^*$ for the conjunction of the axioms of $\mathcal T$, we have that the last fact means that :

> $\vdash (T^* \land \lnot A) \Rightarrow A$ [i.e. $(T^* \land \lnot A) \Rightarrow A$ is *true*]

and this in turn is equivalent to :

> $\vdash T^* \Rightarrow ( \lnot A \Rightarrow A)$

by the *tautology* : $p \Rightarrow (q \Rightarrow r) \Leftrightarrow (p \land q ) \Rightarrow r$ [see : [Exportation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exportation_%28logic%29)].

Thus, under the assumption that $\mathcal T \cup \{ \lnot A \}$ is contradictory, we conclude by *modus ponens* that :

> > $\mathcal T \vdash \lnot A \Rightarrow A$.

---

---

Finally, we prove that :

> > if $\mathcal T \cup \{ \lnot A \}$ is contradictory, then $\mathcal T \vdash A$.

1) $\mathcal T \cup \{ \lnot A \}$ is contradictory --- premise

2) $\mathcal T \vdash \lnot A \Rightarrow A$ --- from 1)

3) if $\vdash A \Rightarrow A$ and $\vdash \lnot A \Rightarrow A$, then $\vdash A$ --- from *Lemma 4*

> 4) $\mathcal T \vdash A$ --- from 2), 3) and (TL2) : $\vdash A \Rightarrow A$ [see page 28].