# Why might Dieudonne have been "begging the question" by appealing to second-order Peano Axioms?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, logic, philosophy, foundations, peano-axioms

Following a [comment by Peter Smith](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/264913/book-on-the-rigorous-foundations-of-mathematics-logic-and-set-theory/265346#265346), I've been reading A. R. D. Mathias's paper [The Ignorance of Bourbaki](https://www.dpmms.cam.ac.uk/~ardm/bourbaki.pdf).

Parts of the paper are above my head, but I understand it well enough for my own amateurish purposes - apart from one sentence.

The context is a quotation from Dieudonne's *A Panorama of Pure Mathematics* (1982):

> The first axiomatic treatments (Dedekind-Peano arithmetic, Hilbert Euclid geometry) dealt with univalent theories , i.e. theories which are entirely determined by their complete system of axioms, unlike the theory of groups.

Mathias's commentary on this passage ends with the following sentence, which baffles me:

> In saying that Peano arithmetic is univalent, Bourbaki probably has in mind some second-order characterisation of the standard model of arithmetic,
>   which is, of course, to beg the question.

I can only imagine that he means that even the second-order axioms cannot stand on their own, because any such version of the Peano Axioms has two hidden prerequisites:

1. Reference to a particular (but unmentioned) version of set theory.
2. Reference to a "standard model of arithmetic", whose existence and uniqueness is silently taken for granted (thus "begging the question" in a simpler sense than item 1).

But neither of these ideas is really clear to me, nor do I have any idea whether the author is alluding to either of them, both of them, or neither.

(When one is confused, it is hard to explain the precise way in which one is confused!)

If the meaning of the quoted sentence is not obvious to others, I'll consider asking the author himself about it via e-mail, but I'm marginally less nervous about posting a question here - and perhaps an answer to the question here will also interest others.

The paper is about Bourbaki's blind spot in relation to developments in logic since 1929. As my own blind spots are incomparably more severe than any of Bourbaki's, it is entirely possible that I will fail to understand a perfectly good explanation of the meaning of the above sentence!

But I will be well enough satisfied by an answer that reduces my current bafflement, by one sentence in an otherwise intelligible paper, to a more familiar perplexity about mathematics itself.

Comment: It brings cheer to my heart to see somebody actually use the phrase "beg the question" correctly.  It has to be one of the most mis-used phrases of all time.  I can't get used to it, when I hear professional journalists use it wrong it makes me cringe, every time.

Comment: @GregoryGrant This begs the question: What is the correct use? -- Oops, sorry :)

Comment: @GregoryGrant: "beg the question" is often misused because it's a meaningless and unidiomatic cliche arising from a mistranslation of a latin translation of a phrase used by Aristotle. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Begging_the_question. I think it is better to shun the phrase rather than admire the odd case where the mistranslation is used in the original sense.

Comment: Returning to the question, I think Bourbaki's "univalent" is unclear and is probably intended to mean something like [categorical](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category_theory). Mathias is (I think) pointing out that the statement that such-and-such a first-order theory is categorical presupposes a meta-theory in which you can reason about its categoricity. So I agree with your analysis.

Comment: @RobArthan  First off no, it's not a "cliche".  Secondly, not only does it have a precise meaning, but if we shun its correct meaning then how else do we describe the logical fallacy it refers to?  As far as I know,  that's the name of the fallacy and it has no other name.  So we can't really shun it.  Furthermore English is full of unidiomatic expressions, were we to shun them all then we'd lose some of the character of our language.

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen Well how you used it is exactly the wrong way.  It really means to assume in your argument that which you are trying to prove.  An example would be to say "The bible is true, because it says so right in the bible."

Comment: @RobArthan I certainly took 'univalent' to mean 'categorical'. On the main point, I fail to see that the requirement for a meta-theory in which categoricity can be proved is a case of the fallacy of *petitio principii* [said he, diplomatically!] - a term which surely implies presupposing the conclusion of the proof, not merely the existence of some logical framework in which the proof may be constructed. (But I'll mull this over some more, in case it is - all too predictably - falling upon one of my blind spots.)

Comment: @GregoryGrant Hagen was joking.

Comment: *petitio principii* is great by me. I think Mathias's point is that Bourbachistes were trying to reason about what logical framework to work in an unspecified logical framework.

Comment: @GregoryGrant: how about "petitio principii"? Or just "circular argument"?  The character of our language can perhaps be improved by dropping some dross. By the way, what is the name of the fallacious rhetorical device where someone disputes a particular statement by generalising it and then disputing the generalisation?

Comment: By the way, "Bourbaki's blind spot in relation to developments in logic" is likely to be a consequence of the premature death of [Jacques Herbrandt](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jacques_Herbrand). Herbrandt entered Ecole Normale Supérieure (ranked number 1) in 1925 and Dieudonné in 1924. Unfortunately, Herbrandt died in July 1931 as he was mountain-climbing in the French Alps. Claude Chevalley said that "Jacques Herbrand would have hated Bourbaki", but one can rather think that he would have strongly influenced Bourbaki in logic.

Comment: The Boubaki project began in the 1930's so older editions of books in the series will likely be dated with respect to more recent developments.

Comment: By the way the original versions of Peano : *Arithmetices principia: nova methodo exposita* (1889) and Dedekind : *Was sind und was sollen die Zahlen?* (1893) used the second-order version of the Induction axiom, of course in atime when the distinction between f-o and s-o was not clear. See this [post](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1598201/peano-arithmetic-before-g%c3%b6del) for details and links.

Comment: The quote is **not** from Jean Dieudonné, [A panorama of pure mathematics, as seen by N. Bourbaki](https://books.google.it/books?id=1V4-kdN6aGkC&printsec=frontcover) (1982); I'm trying to locate it.

Answer (score 7):

By "In saying that Peano arithmetic is univalent", they assert that there is only one model of Peano arithmetic (up to isomorphism). But this is not the case, since there are nonstandard models of arithmetic. However second-order Peano axioms are categorical. So the assertion makes sense if they had in mind a second-order axiomatization. But let's take a look at the following commentary by Mathias:

> My reading of all these extracts is that Bourbaki had grasped the positive worth of the work of Hilbert
>   and his school, and welcomed the idea of the reduction of the question of correctness of mathematics to a
>   set of rules, but nevertheless persisted, even after Gödel’s work showed that Hilbert’s program could never
>   be completed, in thinking of logic and set theory as stuff one settled in Volume One and then forgot about.

So basically, by finding their way to the uniqueness of true arithmetic, he interprets this appeal to second-order axioms as negating all the subtleties introduced by the incompleteness, equating "true" and "provable". While this erroneous view can still somehow work when thinking about arithmetic, it fails miserably when applied to set theory, which makes the position fairly untenable. The author then goes on to explain that this mathematical misconception found its origin in French philosophical tradition.

> But whatever the reason, the fact remains that they did not accommodate Gödel’s incompleteness theorems in their view of mathematics: and no sociological or psychological explanation of Bourbaki’s resistance to Gödel’s insights can resolve the mathematical and philosophical difficulties presented by Gödel’s work to believers in Hilbert’s programme.

Comment: Darn nice answer, by the way. You address OP's actual question better than I did.

Answer (score 6):

Second order PA (2oPA) is "univalent" aka categorical, in the strong sense that, when using standard, "full" 2nd order semantics, its only model is the standard model of arithmetic. The only thing "2nd order" about 2oPA is the induction axiom, which is no longer a schema but a single sentence which quantifies over *all* subsets. In "full" 2nd order semantics, "all subsets" really means just that, whereas in Henkin semantics, the 2nd order set quantifier ranges merely over the sets *of the model*, which form a collection that's closed under requisite operations (union, intersection, complement, projection, etc.) but which might not be the full powerset.

As you noticed, full 2nd order semantics implicitly references a background set theory — not a "version" of set theory, but actually a model $M$ of set theory (specifically, its powerset of $\omega$, $\mathcal{P}(\Bbb \omega)^M = \mathcal{P}(\Bbb \omega)\cap M$). However, the notion of a (/the) standard model of arithmetic is hardly controversial. If we can't agree on what is and isn't "in there", then we can't agree on much else, and we won't have a metatheory of anything.

---

Readers who liked the cited paper of Adrian Mathias also like his follow-up, [A term of length 4,523,659,424,929](https://www.dpmms.cam.ac.uk/~ardm/inefff.pdf). ***Abstract***: Bourbaki suggest that their definition of the number 1 runs to some tens of thousands of symbols. We show that that is a considerable under-estimate, the true number of symbols being that in the title, not counting 1,179,618,517,981 disambiguatory links.

Comment: Thank you for the reference, this paper is fantastic. Bourbaki's book on set theory is really a gift that keeps on giving. Although not for its intended interpretation.

Comment: You're welcome. *Théorie des Ensembles* is indeed an odd system, all right, but nevertheless a very good book :) The exercises are a fine collection, too. Of course, none concern foundations, just straight theorems of ZC.

Comment: "The implications for Bourbaki's philosophical claims and the mental health of their readers are discussed." I may well enjoy reading that paper, too - especially because I'm almost sure that my reading, at an impressionable age, of the very Bourbakian $\S0$ of Roger Godement's *Algebra* had a deleterious effect on my mental health! "Also we recommend [the beginner]  to take all definitions of technical terms *absolutely literally*."

Comment: @CalumGilhooley Yes, you will. "The implications..." is quite hilarious :D.

Comment: By the way, there's a really strong justification (beside the minimality argument) for the standard model, Tennenbaum's theorem.

Comment: @Graffitics Yes, Tennenbaum's theorem is quite relevant. If not the standard model, then ... what model are you talking about? Go on, define it: I dare you.

Comment: The tau operator is at least useful to beginners as obviating axiom of choice. Defining quantifiers in terms of it would seem to make using theorem of equivalence unwieldy. But having a natural canonical form (called, say, a *form*ula) for each statement so variant statements are identical as formulas? Useful. E.g., remove variables from quantifiers and replace each occurrence of a bound variable with a string indicating merely how many quantifiers containing the occurrence in its scope must be skipped over before reaching the quantifier binding the occurrence. Links just off somewhat.

Comment: In the paper about the enormous term, Mathias concludes: "For really the debacle is hardly Bourbaki's fault. The founding fathers [of Bourbaki] were keen to introduce Hilbertian standards of rigour to France; and in their youthful enthusiasm they swallowed the Hilbertian promise of a complete and consistent mathematical system hook, line and sinker." <cont...>

Comment: <...cont> "Their formalism rests on a device of Hilbert with which he pursued the chimera of consistency proofs. In the analysis of a complete system, the $\varepsilon$-operator might make sense, but in an incomplete system, such as Godel showed all moderately expressive reasonable fragments of mathematics to be, it becomes very tortuous, and not something to place at the centre of a serious exposition of mathematical truth."

Comment: As Quine used to call second-order logic, "set theory in sheep's clothing".

Comment: @Graffitics: do you know if anyone has written about that argument, relating Tennenbaum's theorem to categoricity?  It's an interesting question, since every nonstandard model of PA believes that it is recursive too.

Comment: @Carl Mummert Unfortunately I don't, but would be interested to know about it if such a link can be established.

Answer (score 4):

*Comment* to Graffitics's answer.

The quote is from:

- Nicolas Bourbaki, *L'architecture des mathematiques*, into [François Le Lionnais](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fran%C3%A7ois_Le_Lionnais) (ed.), *Les grands courants de la pensée mathématique* (1948), page 45. See [Engl.transl.](https://books.google.it/books?id=CY6OMeJ0M4gC&pg=PA35), page 35.

The issue is not (according to my understanding) about first-order vs second-order axiomatization.

Bourbaki is discussing the (seminal) notions of *méthode axiomatique* and of *structure*:

> [page 40 - Engl.transl., page 28](https://books.google.it/books?id=CY6OMeJ0M4gC&pg=PA28) - On peut maintenant faire comprendre ce qu'il faut entendre, d'une façon générale, par une *structure mathématique*. [...] Faire la théorie axiomatique d'une structure donnée, c'est déduire les conséquences 
>   logiques des axiomes de la structure, *en s'interdisant toute autre hypothèse 
>   sur les éléments considérés* (en particulier, toute hypothèse sur leur «nature» propre).
>
> [page 41](https://books.google.it/books?id=CY6OMeJ0M4gC&pg=PA29) -  Les relations qui forment le point de départ de la définition d'une 
>   structure peuvent être de nature assez variée. Celle qui intervient dans les 
>   structures de groupe est ce qu'on appelle une «loi de composition», 
>   c'est-à-dire une relation entre trois éléments déterminant le troisième 
>   de façon unique en fonction des deux premiers. Lorsque les relations de 
>   définition d'une structure sont des «lois de composition», la structure 
>   correspondante est appelée *structure algébrique*.
>
> [page 43](https://books.google.it/books?id=CY6OMeJ0M4gC&pg=PA32) - Guidés par la conception axiomatique, essayons donc de nous représenter l'ensemble de l'univers mathématique. Certes, nous n'y reconnaîtrons 
>   plus guère l'ordre traditionnel, qui, tel celui des premières nomenclatures 
>   des espèces animales, se bornait à ranger côte à côte les théories qui présentaient le plus de ressemblances extérieures. Au lieu des compartiments bien délimités de l'Algèbre, de l'Analyse, de la Théorie des Nombres 
>   et de la Géométrie, nous verrons, par exemple, la théorie des nombres 
>   premiers voisiner avec celle des courbes algébriques, ou la géométrie 
>   euclidienne avec les équations intégrales; et le principe ordonnateur sera 
>   la conception d'une *hiérarchie de structures*, allant du simple au complexe, 
>   du général au particulier.

In this context we have to read the final remark about:

> [page 45 - Engl.transl., page 35](https://books.google.it/books?id=CY6OMeJ0M4gC&pg=PA35) - les premières axiomatisations, 
>   et qui eurent le plus de retentissement (celles de l'arithmétique avec 
>   Dedekind et Peano, de la géométrie euclidienne avec Hilbert) portaient 
>   sur des théories *univalentes*, c'est-à-dire telles que le système global 
>   de leurs axiomes les déterminait entièrement, et n'était 'par suite susceptible de s'appliquer à aucune théorie autre que celle d'où on l'avait extrait 
>   (au rebours de ce que nous avons vu pour la théorie des groupes, par 
>   exemple).

Dedekind-Peano axiomatization, as well as Euclid-Hilbert's one, aims at the "univocal characterization" of its *intended structure*.

According to Bourbaki's point of view, the "general" notion of *structure* is mathematically more interesting and fruitfully.

---

*Note*

Mathias' concern about the meager attention by Bourbaki regrading mathematical logic is correct; see:

> [page 37 - Engl.transl., page 25](https://books.google.it/books?id=CY6OMeJ0M4gC&pg=PA25) - toute théorie mathématique est un enchaînement de propositions, se déduisant les unes des autres conformément aux règles d'une logique qui, pour l'essentiel, est celle codifiée depuis Aristote sous le nom de «logique formelle», convenablement adaptée aux buts particuliers du mathématicien. C'est donc un truisme banal de dire que ce «raisonnement déductif» est un principe d'unité pour la mathématique [...]. Le mode de raisonnement par enchaînement de syllogismes n'est qu'un *mécanisme* transformateur, applicable indifféremment à toutes sortes de prémisses, et qui ne saurait donc caractériser la nature de celles-ci. [...] Codifier ce langage, en ordonner le vocabulaire et en clarifier la syntaxe, c'est faire œuvre fort utile, et qui constitue effectivement une face de la méthode axiomatique, celle qu'on peut proprement appeler le *formalisme logique* (ou, comme on dit aussi, la «logistique»). Mais - et nous insistons sur ce point - *ce n'en est qu'une face*, et la moins intéressante.

As noted by Mathias, Bourbaki (in 1948) seems totally unaware of Gödel's results of [1931](http://plato.stanford.edu/entries/goedel/#IncThe) regarding the *incompleteness of arithmetic* and of [1940](http://plato.stanford.edu/entries/goedel/#GodWorSetThe) regarding *the consistency of the Continuum Hypothesis and the Axiom of Choice* and their impact with the subsequent development of mathematical logic as a mathematical discipline: model theory, set theory, computability, etc.

Comment: I am curious about your comment concerning the *intended structure*.  Are you quoting Bourbaki here or offering your own insight?  See also [here](http://mathoverflow.net/questions/232584)

Comment: @user72694 - the quoting from B are highlighted; thus, it is my comment.

Comment: I wonder if Bourbaki would agree with your summary.

Comment: @user72694 - but the "idea" of "intended interpretation" is clearly present in Dedekind; see Richard Dedekind, [Essays on the Theory of Numbers (1872-1888)](http://www.gutenberg.org/files/21016/21016-pdf.pdf), page 34: **Th.79**. $N$ is the only number-chain containing
the base-number $1$.

Comment: Theorem 79 is a proof of induction. This would hold in any model of PA. Besides, my comment mainly concerned Bourbaki, not Dedekind.

Comment: @user72694 - B says: "les premières axiomatisations (celles de l'arithmétique avec Dedekind et Peano) portaient sur des théories univalentes, c'est-à-dire telles que le système global de leurs axiomes les déterminait entièrement, et n'était par suite susceptible de s'appliquer à aucune théorie autre que celle d'où on l'avait extrait". Thus he clearly consider the **unique** structure satisfying D-P (second order) axioms.

Comment: Mauro, that's exactly right and that's precisely Mathias' problem with Bourbaki, that their terminology does not even allow one to speak of other possible interpretations. The terminology you introduced, namely *intended structure*, alludes to a possibility of *other* interpretations.  This would make Mathias happy but not Nicolas :-)

Comment: @user72694 - I'm not sure of fully grasping your comments... My thought is "twofold": i) Bourbaki seems quite "uninterested" in math log as a mathematical discipline; if I'm right, there is no *Model Theory* chapter in B's *Elements*. Consider Diedonné's *Panorama* (1982): only 8 pages for math log. This for my "agreement" with Mathias.

Comment: But - and this is my concern with my answer to the OP's question - I simply cannot imagine that a team of first-class mathematiciasn like those forming B, have not "understood" Godel's Th and the implications regarding the existence of non-standard models and the "gap" between the f-o axiom schema of induction and the "full" Dedekind and Peano versione of induction.

Comment: Mauro, did you read Mathias' text?

Comment: Yes, and my "agreement" with him is about "Why did the Bourbachistes not adapt their attitudes to take account of the supremely important contribution of Godel to foundational issues ?" The answer: "because they were French" is debatable... but I've no betetr explanation. But what means Mathias with "In saying that Peano arithmetic is univalent,
Bourbaki probably has in mind some second-order characterisation of the standard model of arithmetic, which is, of course, to beg the question."? My comments is: "yes, they consider the "natural" s-o axiomatization",

Comment: Which paper of Mathias did you read? I realized we may not be talking about the same paper.  Try reading his "hilbert, bourbaki, and the scorning of logic." It provides answers to all your questions.

Comment: @user72694 - ARD Mathias, [The Ignorance of Bourbaki](https://www.dpmms.cam.ac.uk/~ardm/bourbaki.pdf) (1990), that linked to the OP's question above.

Comment: @user72694 - Thanks, I'll do. Please, note this unwanted coincidence; see the comment of mine to this old [post](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/677421/proving-in-a-hilbert-system-that-neg-a-rightarrow-a-is-a-theorem-if-assuming) about Godement: at that time I've been harshly reprimended by the OP of the question :-)

Comment: Exactly :-) The confusion of truth and provability in Bourbaki is precisely the focus of Mathias later text which is over 100 pages. It is obviously related to Bourbaki's philosophical commitment to a unique set-theoretic universe, period :-)

Comment: P.S. Incidentally I see you seem to know a lot about sources. Would you have any ideas for my question http://mathoverflow.net/questions/232584/looking-for-a-source-for-intended-interpretation ?