# Proving that L1 and L2 have the same theorems.

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus

[From "Introduction to Mathmatical logic" by Elliott Mendelson,exercise 1.58]

Axioms of $L_1$:
(A1) $B \rightarrow (C \rightarrow B)$ 
(A2) $(B \rightarrow (C \rightarrow D)) \rightarrow ((B \rightarrow C) \rightarrow (B \rightarrow D))$ 
(A3) $(\lnot C \rightarrow \lnot B ) \rightarrow ((\lnot C \rightarrow B) \rightarrow C)$

only rule of inference is $MP$

Axiom system of $L_2$: 
(B1) $(\lnot B \rightarrow B) \rightarrow B$ 
(B2) $B \rightarrow (\lnot B \rightarrow C)$ 
(B3) $(B \rightarrow C) \rightarrow ((C \rightarrow D) \rightarrow (B \rightarrow D))$

only rule of inference is $MP$

I have to prove that $L_1$ and $L_2$ have the same theorems.For that I have to prove that the axioms of $L_1$ can be proven from axioms of $L_2$ and vice-versa (both systems have the same inferences so I don't have to worry about that).I was able to prove the axioms of $L_2$ from the axioms $L_1$ (in $L_1$) , but failed at proving the axioms of $L_1$ from the axioms of $L_2$ (in $L_2$).

The theorems I was able to derive in $L_2$ so far were:-
(1) $\vdash_{L_2} B \rightarrow B$ 
(2) $B \rightarrow C, C \rightarrow D \vdash_{L_2} B \rightarrow D$ 
(3) $B \rightarrow C \vdash_{L_2} ((C \rightarrow D) \rightarrow (B \rightarrow D))$ 
(4) $\vdash_{L_2}(\lnot B \rightarrow B) \rightarrow (\lnot B \rightarrow C)$ 
(5) $\vdash_{L_2}B \to (\lnot B \to B)$ 
(6) $\vdash_{L_2}(B \to C) \to ((\lnot B \to B) \to C)$ 
(7) $\vdash_{L_2}((\lnot B \to B) \to C) \to (B \to C)$ 
(8) $\vdash_{L_2}B \to ((B \to D) \to (\lnot B \to D))$ 
(9) $\vdash_{L_2}\lnot (B \to B) \to (B \to B)$ 
(10) $\vdash_{L_2} (B\to(\lnot B \to \lnot C)) \to (((\lnot B \to \lnot C) \to (C \to B)) \to (B \to (C \to B)))$ 
(11) $\vdash_{L_2} ((\lnot B \to \lnot C) \to (C \to B)) \to (B \to (C \to B))$ 
(12)  $\vdash_{L_2} (B\to(\lnot B \to \lnot C)) \to (((\lnot B \to \lnot C) \to D) \to (B \to D)))$ 
(13)  $\vdash_{L_2} ((\lnot B \to \lnot C) \to D) \to (B \to D) $ 
(14)  $\vdash_{L_2} ((\lnot B \to \lnot C) \to C) \to (B \to C) $ 
But I still am a long way from proving the axioms of $L_2$ from $L_1$ .The problem is that I have ran out of ideas about how I can manipulate the axioms of $L_2$.Can someone give me a hint about this?

**Edit**:I found another axiom system in another post which I will call $L_3$.

Axioms of $L_3$: 
(C1) $B \to (C \to B)$ 
(C2) $(B \to (C \to D)) \to ((B \to C) \to (B \to D))$ 
(C3) $(\lnot B \rightarrow B) \rightarrow B$ 
(C4) $\lnot B \rightarrow (B \rightarrow C)$

idk , maybe I should try to prove (C1) and (C2) from (B3) in $L_2$ as a subgoal/lemma [Not sure if it will help me with my main problem of proving the axioms of $L_1$ from the axioms of $L_2$ (in $L_2$)].

I found a wiki article [List of Hilbert systems](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Hilbert_systems) where, $L_1$ is called "Mendelsons axiom system" and $L_2$ is called "Łukasiewicz First Axiom system".I tried to find a paper,book or article about "Łukasiewicz First Axiom system" instead of the wiki article of Hilbert systems, but the only thing I was able to get that uses "Łukasiewicz First Axiom system" was this MIT OCW lecture slide [An example of usage of "Łukasiewicz First Axiom system"](https://ocw.mit.edu/courses/electrical-engineering-and-computer-science/6-042j-mathematics-for-computer-science-spring-2015/lecture-slides/MIT6_042JS16_PropositLogic.pdf).There, they derived $\vdash_{L_2} B \to B$ and stopped.I also tried to searching "lukaweicz" to see if someone has a similar question like mine,but the questions I found were actually about "lukaweicz **third** axiom system", not "lukaweicz **first** axiom system" [an example](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3569611/what-is-the-proof-of-reductio-ad-absurdum-raa-in-a-%C5%81ukasiewicz-axiom-system-fo). I will be glad if someone shows me some other reference that I can read.

Comment: I'd be interested to see your derivations for the theorems--- might give some hints of how to work with MP and axioms of $L_1.$

Comment: You'd make life easier for us if you didn't use the same labels for different axioms. Systems L1 and L3 are (I think I recall) reasonably easy to prove equivalent, as in both we have the two axioms [A1, A2 of L1] that let us show we can add the rule DT (Dedn Thm). The same is true for L3', got by tweaking the 4th axiom of L3 by swapping $B$ and $\neg B$. Now the axioms of L2 are a subset of the axioms of L3', so it's clear exactly which proposition you need to prove in L2 [$B\to(C\to B)$]. I should add that I always find Mendelson's exercises challenging.

Comment: @ancientmathematician ok I edited so that I use different labels for different axioms.Thanks for mentioning.

Comment: You've done it in a very opaque way with all these subscripts! And it really would help if you didn't use different names for the same proposition.

Comment: "You've done it in a very opaque way with all these subscripts!",I assume I did a bad job of fixing.sorry for that.Is there another way I can make it more transparent to someone who will answer my question? Also , didn't quite understood what you meant by "And it really would help if you didn't use different names for the same proposition."

Comment: A1=C1; A2=C2; B1=C3; B2=C4' (where C4' is C4 with the $B$ and $\neg B$ swapped; this does not alter the system L3 since we have the DT in L3).

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA can you show me what are the important breakthroughs I need to derive a heep of theorems in L2? (I dont have access to that book)

Comment: Sorry... I've browsed  it  and I've found (A1) and (A2) of L1 around number 40 of L's derived theorems. Thus, the work of copying them up to that point is worthless.

Comment: It's not possible to prove {CbCcb, CCbCcdCCbcCbd} from CCbcCCcdCbd.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Example* from Jan Łukasiewicz, [Elements of Mathematical Logic (Pergamon Press, 1963)](https://books.google.it/books?id=Eyq4AAAAIAAJ&q=Jan+%C5%81ukasiewicz+Elements+of+Mathematical+Logic), page 42.

Starting from your axiom (B3) $[(p \to q) \to ((q \to r) \to (p \to r))]$ with substitution: $[p \leftarrow (p \to q), q \leftarrow ((q \to r)\to(p \to r)), r \leftarrow s]$ we get:

> $[((p \to q) \to ((q \to r)\to(p \to r))) \to ((((q \to r)\to(p \to r)) \to s) \to ((p \to q) \to s))]$

The antecedent is (B3) again; thus, by Modus Ponens, we get:

> (T4) $(((q \to r)\to(p \to r)) \to s) \to ((p \to q) \to s)$.

In the same way (from (T4) and a suitable substitution) we get:

> (T5) $[(p \to (q \to r))] \to ((s \to q) \to [p \to(s \to r)]).$

The basic "proof technique" is to identify a suitable substitution in some axiom or already proven thesis such that the result is a "big" conditional where the antecedent is an axiom or an already proven thesis and the consequent is the thesis to be proved.

We can see it in the derivation of $p \to p$ [page 45: your (1)].

From (B3) again, with substitution $[q \leftarrow (\lnot p \to q)]$ we get: $[p \to (\lnot p \to q)] \to [((\lnot p \to q) \to r) \to (p \to r)]$.

The antecedent is axiom (B2) and thus by MP we get (T9): $((\lnot p \to q) \to r) \to (p \to r)$ [*that seems quite strange*...].

Now, from (T9) with substitution $[q \leftarrow p, r \leftarrow p]$ we get: $((\lnot p \to p) \to p) \to (p \to p)$.

The antecedent is axiom is (B1); using MP we get: (T16) $p \to p$.

Going on, we have [page 45]: (T18) $q \to (p \to q)$ [which is (A1) of L1], and "the very important *law of commutation*" [page 47]: (T21) $(p \to (q \to r)) \to (q \to (p \to r))$.

Then [page 49]: (T35) $(p \to (q \to r)) \to [(p \to q) \to (p \to r)]$ [which is (A2) of L1].

> Thesis 35 occurs as an axiom in the first axiom system of the sentential calculus, given by Frege in his *Begriffsschrift*.

---

*The main difficulty in Łukasiewicz's original book is the lack of the* $\text { Deduction Theorem}$.

Regarding axiom (A3) of L1, we can use "the very important law of *double
negation*" [page 50]:

> (T39) $\lnot \lnot p \to p$ and (T40) $p \to \lnot \lnot p$,

as well as "the four *laws of transposition*" [page 51]:

> (T46) $(p \to q) \to (\lnot q \to \lnot p)$, etc.

What we can do now is to use (T46): $(\lnot q \to p) \vdash (\lnot p \to \lnot \lnot q)$ with (T39) and your (2) above to get:

> $(\lnot q \to p) \vdash (\lnot p \to q)$.

Using it with $(\lnot q \to \lnot p)$ and (2) again we get:

> $(\lnot q \to \lnot p), (\lnot q \to p) \vdash (\lnot q \to q)$.

Finally, using axiom (B1) of L2 and MP we get:

> > $(\lnot q \to \lnot p), (\lnot q \to p) \vdash q$.

Comment: Never thought of trying to get bigger theorems from smaller theorems (and "MP-ing" them). Thanks for the hint.